# How to get exact offsetLeft and offsetTop values?

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML**

```
 <body>     
 <div class="col-lg-8 text-center"> 
        <div class="well col-lg-12" id="TwoPlayer">
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg right" id="backButtonTP1">Home</a></p>    
            <button id="new1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left">New Game</button>
            <canvas id="tttBoard"  width="500px" height="500px">Your browser does not seem to support the canvas element. Try Firefox or Chrome!</canvas>
            <script>window.TicTacToe.drawBoard();window.TicTacToe.drawMark(col,row);</script>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
if (e.pageX != undefined && e.pageY != undefined)
{
    x = e.pageX;    
    y = e.pageY;
    console.log(x,y);
}
else
{
    x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}

x -= elem.offsetLeft;
y -= elem.offsetTop;
```

When ever i am placing this two player div inside another div for which bootstrap is applied, it is giving wrong offset-top and offset-left values. If i place the div outside the parent div offset-top and offset-left values are correctly displaying.what may be the reason for this. Help me to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The offset is always relative to it's parent. So if you want an offset relative to the document you need to get the offsets of all its ancestors. I didn't test it, just wrote it down here.

```
var f = e;
var offsetLeft = 0;
var offsetTop = 0;

while( ( f = f.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() ) != 'html' ){
  var gbcr = f.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetLeft += Math.round(gbcr.left);
  offsetTop  += Math.round(gbcr.top);
}
```

If that works, then it should give you the offsets relative to the body.

If you need only the offset relative to its parent element, you just use the body of the while

```
var boundingRectangle = e.getBoundingClientRect();
var offsetLeft = Math.round(boundingRectangle.left);
var offsetTop = Math.round(boundingRectangle.top);
```

Comment: what is the tagName mentioned here ?

Comment: It will retrieve the tag name of the node. For example if your node is div then it will return "div"